# Right Arrow Key Navigation Shortcut Issue

Tags: release-loki, settings, keyboard-shortcuts

My system is an Acer Inspiron E 15 which is running on Elementary OS Loki. The issue I've found that randomly started today was discovered during my use of Google Docs via Chrome. I clicked the right arrow key to navigate to a specific sentence and Music opens up instead of actually going right in Google Docs. Left works fine, but right seems to open up Music and I'm not sure why. I've looked at Keyboard Shortcuts but nothing is there. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:** Now my left and right arrow key opens the Music app. Very strange.